# Visual Studio Continue (Play) and Break All (Pause) buttons both disabled sometimes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Both the continue and pause buttons show as disabled sometimes after I click the break/pause button when I'm debugging release builds with Visual Studio 2010.  The call stack also shows as empty and the process being debugged stops making any progress and uses 0 CPU.  This makes it impossible to continue debugging, forcing me to restart debugging.

[image: continue and break buttons both grayed out]

Anyone know what causes this to happen and how to work around it?  Sometimes it takes me a few minutes to stop VS debugging and get it back into the needed state, so it is really a time drain when this happens.

This only seems to occur when I pause execution during one function, which I think VS is inlining in the release build -- not sure if that is relevant.  This is a native 64-bit C++ console application.  I need to sometimes debug in release because execution is sometimes too slow in debug.

---

My VS version:

[image: VS Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2010 are you using exactly.  What type of project are you trying to debug?  What build mode are you trying to debug, if its release mode, switch to debug mode.

Comment: @Ramhound: I added that information to the question: VS 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel, native C++ console application, and I need to debug in release in this case because debug mode is too slow.

Comment: If I am careful to not pause during execution of this one function, then I can't reproduce the problem.  Programming on Windows is infuriating -- I never have problems like this developing on Linux.

Comment: This a 32-bit or 64-bit process.  VS2010 ability to debug and continue a 64-bit was limited.  If you hit break during the debugging process your already ending the debugging and process should end.  You sure this isn't a code problem?

Comment: This is 64-bit.  I am sure this isn't a code problem, but even if there was a bug in my code, the debugger shouldn't cease being able to pause/continue with no call stack information.

Comment: Ramhound: do you have a source saying that you can't continue after hitting a break point while debugging 64-bit in VS2010?  That sounds bogus and contradicts my frequent experience debugging 64-bit with VS 2010.

Comment: @Ramhound, I think you're thinking of Edit-and Continue.  AFAIK, debug and continue has always been supported and would be a pretty basic feature of a debugger.

Comment: @jdimatteo, are you sure the process is actually getting stopped by the debugger?  From what you're describing it doesn't sound like execution is ever broken.

Comment: @heavyd: yes, the process is getting stopped by the debugger.  I press the break/pause button which triggers this state and then the process CPU usage goes from a full core to zero.

Comment: I guess this is just an uncommon VS bug with no available explanation/workaround.  I was hoping the bug was at least commonly encountered so others had seen this and could suggest how to continue debugging when in this state so I don't have to just restart debugging.

Comment: If it's of any consolation, the same issue also happens to me with Visual Studio 2015 :(